# having issues with Java reading input files using netbeans

Tags: java, file, input, netbeans

Following is my code that I am working on for a school project. It does ok up until I try to read the animal.txt file.  Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am attaching my compilation error as an image.  Thanks in advance.

[input error image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVfe5.png)

```
   package finalproject;

      //enabling java programs
      import java.util.Scanner;
      import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Monitoring {

```
public static void choseAnimal() throws IOException{
    FileInputStream file = null;
    Scanner inputFile = null;
    System.out.println("Here is your list of animals");
     file = new FileInputStream("\\src\\finalproject\\animals.txt");
     inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    while(inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}

 public static void choseHabit(){
System.out.println("Here is your list of habits");

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String mainOption = ""; //user import for choosing animal, habit or exit
    String exitSwitch = "n"; // variable to allow exit of system
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); // setup to allow user imput




    System.out.println("Welcome to the Zoo");
    System.out.println("What would you like to monitor?");
    System.out.println("An animal, habit or exit the system?");
    mainOption = scnr.next();
    System.out.println("you chose " + mainOption);
    if (mainOption.equals("exit")){
    exitSwitch = "y";
    System.out.println(exitSwitch);
    }
    if (exitSwitch.equals( "n")){
        System.out.println("Great, let's get started");
    }
        if (mainOption.equals("animal")){
            choseAnimal();

        }
        if (mainOption.equals("habit")) {
            choseHabit();

        }

    else {
        System.out.println("Good bye");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Don't, ever reference `src` in your code, it won't exist once the program is built and packaged.  Netbeans automatically packages everything in the `src` directory into the result jar file

Comment: You also can't treat a resource of this type as a file, you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to be able to read it

Answer (score 1):

`\\src\\finalproject\\animals.txt` suggests that the file is an embedded resource.

First, you should never reference `src` in you code, it won't exist once the program is built and package.

Secondly, you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` in order to read.

Something more like...

```
//file = new FileInputStream("\\src\\finalproject\\animals.txt");
//inputFile = new Scanner(file);

try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(Monitoring.class.getResourceAsStream("/finalproject/animals.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()) {
    //...
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

for example

Now, this assumes that file `animals.txt` exists in the `finalproject` package

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly shows that it can't find the file. This means there's two possibilities:

1. File does not exist in the directory you want
2. Directory you want is not the directory you have.

I would start by creating a `File` object looking at `"."` (current directory) to and printing that to see what directory it looks by default. You may need to hard code the file path, depending on what netbeans is using for a default directory.